# Which is better either Viewgroup or Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, grid, android-viewgroup

Am creating a grid in android Now am struck with either to use ViewGroup or Layouts (Frame layout /Linear layout) for creating a container in which the cells will be loaded and it would be helpful if provided with links for detailed learning process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) or [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Viewgroup is derived from views and layouts are derived from view group so better to use layouts.

check [gridlayout](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources)  also